# CoreData concurrency using stack

Tags: swift, core-data, concurrency

I've been getting random crashes that all seem to lead back to concurrency issues. So, I'm trying to do all of my data processing on a private queue. Which seems to be easy enough when using a persistent container:

```
let persistentContainer = CoreDataStack.shared.persistentContainer

persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (context) in
   //get data and save it     
}
```

Here's my question - I have a `saveContext()` function in my core data stack that does more than just save managed objects. So I'd really like to use that function if possible. What happens then if I use the context from my core data stack and not the one declared in `performBackgroundTask`? I tried it, and everything seems to be working just fine. But it's such a random error that I wanted to make sure I haven't just added to the problem.

Comment: I think it would help to explain what you mean by the word *use* in *What happens then if I use…*

Comment: I use the managed object context to save downloaded data. The moc comes from a shared instance that gives me access to a modified version of `save()` from my core data stack called `saveContext()`. But when I use `performBackgroundTask`, it comes with its own context on a private queue. Maybe what I should be asking is if there is a way to use `performBackgroundTask`'s context but still have access to my `saveContext()` method?